# codeigniter 3: does my code follow MVC rule

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter 3 and try to convert my PHP project to MVC by this Framework

Controller file

```
class home extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('frontend/M_Headers');
    }   
    public function index()
    {
        $data['slide_image'] = $this->M_Headers->get_all_slide();
        $this->load->view('frontend/headers',$data);

    }
}
```

Model file

```
class M_Headers extends CI_Model {
    public function __construct()
    {
           parent::__construct();
    }
    public function get_all_slide()
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('tbl_slide');
        return $query->result();

    }
}
```

View file

```
        <div class="slider">
            <ul class="rslides" id="slider">
<?php       
        if(count($slide_image) > 0)
        {
            foreach($slide_image as $value):
                $get_image=$value->sl_image;
                if($get_image != ''):
                    $image_properties = array(
                        'src' => 'assets/images/slide/'.$get_image,
                        'alt' => '',
                    );
?>
                <li><?php echo img($image_properties); ?></li>
                <?php else: ?>
                <li>No Slide</li>
<?php
                endif;
            endforeach;
        }       
?>

            </ul>
        </div>
```

- did am i right that loop result in View or should i do it in
  Controller?
- which query should i use between active record or bind (where id=?) or they had it own benefit in difference situation?

Comment: You should probably post on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: Hi @jeroen does this kind of question only avialable to ask in  codereview.stackexchange.com ? before i remove this and go there ?

Comment: Just a note I would read this for naming classes and file names http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Answer (score 0):

The loop in the view is correct. Because it is "view logic" (repeating li's) you can use into the view.

Your Model can be better. I personally like to use the model as a representation of the item from the database. Like this:

```
class M_Headers extends CI_Model 
{
    private var $tablename = "tbl_slide";

    var $id;
    var $sl_image;

    public function __construct()
    {
       parent::__construct();
    }

    public function get_all_slide()
    {
        $slides = array();
        $query = $this->db->get($this->tablename);
        foreach($query->result() as $row)
        {
             $item = new self();
             $item->id = $row->id;
             $item->sl_image = $row->sl_image;
             $slides[] = $item;
        }
        return $slides;
    }

    public function get_slide($id)
    {
        $this->db->where("id", $id);
        $query = $this->db->get($this->tablename);
        $results = $query->result();
        if(isset($results[0]))
        {
             $row = $results[0];
             $this->id = $row->id;
             $this->sl_image = $row->sl_image;
             return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

You can even improve this to make a method that loads the row into the model:

```
class M_Headers extends CI_Model 
{
    private var $tablename = "tbl_slide";

    var $id;
    var $sl_image;

    public function __construct()
    {
       parent::__construct();
    }

    private function load_with_record($row)
    {
        $this->id = $row->id;
        $this->sl_image = $row->sl_image;
    }

    public function get_all_slide()
    {
        $slides = array();
        $query = $this->db->get($this->tablename);
        foreach($query->result() as $row)
        {
             $item = new self();
             $item->load_with_row($row);
             $slides[] = $item;
        }
        return $slides;
    }

    public function get_slide($id)
    {
        $this->db->where("id", $id);
        $query = $this->db->get($this->tablename);
        $results = $query->result();
        if(isset($results[0]))
        {
             $row = $results[0];
             $this->load_with_row($row);
             return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: is this write as OOP ? i will need time to understand this and modify them.  
    get_slide($id) it mean i can specific slide select by id?  
    how about this 1 load_with_record($row) ?

Comment: I would recommend for you to follow the file and class naming guide for codeigniter http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Comment: I've editted my post to make it more clear, yes this is OOP

Comment: it look a little more easy to understand ; ) i will try to learn and write OOP like this after complete convert my PHP to work in CodeIgniter

Comment: i had 1 more question. i set autoload['library'] to load database so will it close database connection when query done or should i close it manually after query done ?